# Cannot get the innerHTML of a window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, window

HI I have some troubles when reading the text inside a window that I open with `window.open()` I hope you guys can help me, what I need is my parent window will read the `<div>` html value of my child window that the parent window called, 
I have this code but It doesn't works

Parent Window

```
<button onclick="buttonset()">Click me</button>
<script>
var myWindow ;
 function buttonset () {
         myWindow = window.open("pag1.html", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    //myWindow.document.write("<div id='hola'>This is 'myWindow'</div>");
    alert(myWindow.document.getElementById("result").innerHTML);
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

And this is my Child Window (***pag1.html***) code

```
    <body>

<div id="result">1</div>
<div id="msj">Correcto</div>

</body>
```

and when I run it says and just open new window but it doesn't show the message

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: You don't have element with id="result" in pag1.html...

Comment: `window.open` is asynchronous. You're trying to get the contents before the browser has loaded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `load` event of opened `window`

```
myWindow.onload = function() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: For the same reason `load` event is attached to `parent` `window`; to perform task when resources have loaded at the browsing context.

Answer (score 2):

`window.open()` is asynchronous, you need to wait for the document to load.

```
function buttonset () {
    var myWindow = window.open("pag1.html", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.onload = function() {
        alert(myWindow.document.getElementById("result").innerHTML);
        myWindow.close();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page is still loading. So you can attach an inline onload function on the body tag of pag1.html

pag1.html

```
<body onload='doIt()'>   
  <div id="result">1</div>
  <div id="msj">Correcto</div>
  <script>
     function doIt() {
       alert(document.getElementById("result").innerHTML);
    }
   </script>
</body>
```